# react-admin redirect button with parameters from form

Tags: redirect, button, react-admin

I am trying to create a simple form in react admin where to harvest user options for country and language
and then redirect to a 3rd party website using a link constructed with user selection.

```
// in LocationInput.js
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import { useInput } from 'react-admin';

const LocationInput = props => {
    const {
        input,
        meta: { touched, error }
    } = useInput(props);

    return (
        <Select
            label="Location"
            {...input}
        >
            <MenuItem value="GB">United Kingdom</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="SE">Sweden</MenuItem>
        </Select>
            <Select
            label="Language"
            {...input}
        >
            <MenuItem value="en_UK">English</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="sv_SE">Swedish</MenuItem>
        </Select>
     
    );
};
export default LocationInput;
```

```
const LocationEdit = props => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <LocationInput
                source="location"
               
            />
**how do I add a button here to redirect to a link having parameters chosen by the user
ex: https://cnn.com/countryselected/languageselected. (the link is outside of my app in a 3rd party website)**
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
```

Later edit.

I tried to use the redirect functionality as described in official docs: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#redirection-after-submission

However that seems to be constructed only to redirect internally to react-admin routes not to an external website having the URL constructed based on user inputs in my Create Form.

```
const redirect = 'https://cnn.com';
...
const LocationEdit = props => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm redirect={redirect}>
            <LocationInput
                source="location"
               
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<SimpleForm>` is made to edit records. In this example, it seems that you're not trying to persist changes, but only to gather data to later redirect the user. In this case, I wouldn't use `<SimpleForm>`, but rather react-final-form's `<Form>` (see https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/api/Form).

As for the `redirect` prop, it accepts a function value, so you can normally write the following:

```
const redirect = (basePath, id, data) => `'https://cnn.com/location/${data.location}`;
...
const LocationEdit = props => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm redirect={redirect}>
```

Comment: Thank you François  
Indeed I do not want to persist user choices, just harvest country/language and pass it to the redirect programatically created URL.
I tried the quick redirect tip you gave using the SimpleForm and it adds the base url:
**http://localhost:3001/#/mycomponent/https://cnn.com/location/SE/en_UK**
Question is how do I get rid of the url part that is part of my website? (**http://localhost:3001/#/mycomponent/**)

Comment: So it seems the history package, which react-admin uses internally for routing, doesn't accept absolute URLs. There is an open issue on their repo about that (see https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147#issuecomment-113180174). So in order to support what you describe, react-admin needs to bypass history if the location is absolute.

Comment: Would you mind opening an enhancement request with your use case in the react-admin issue tracker on Github?

Comment: I raised it now, 
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/6194
I hope it is well written. If any adjustments to phrasing please let me know. Thank you for taking time to look at my issue.